Bert models show tokenizing statistics
Is there any built-in way to request some tokenizing statistics when using BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased') and BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased') to understand how efficiently my texts are being processed?
I am using texts that are not very large, but their length differentiates from 4 to 250 characters, depending on the training image. The texts sometimes may contain some weird and unpopular words. I am afraid that due to such conditions, the tokenizing process may not be very effective.
I am looking for some way of checking tokenizing statistics when processing all my text images.
I tried using this code, which was founded on Github, but there are a lot of errors inside it and it's not very verbal:
from transformers import BertTokenizer

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

texts = ["This is a sample text.", "Another text with some uncommon words."]

encoded_texts = tokenizer(texts, return_tensors='pt')

# Vocabulary Coverage
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.vocab)
total_tokens = sum([len(text) for text in encoded_texts['input_ids']])
oov_tokens = sum([1 for token in encoded_texts['input_ids'].flatten() if token not in tokenizer.vocab])
vocab_coverage = 1 - (oov_tokens / total_tokens)

# Average Token Length
token_lengths = [len(text) for text in encoded_texts['input_ids']]
average_token_length = sum(token_lengths) / len(token_lengths)

print(f"Vocabulary Coverage: {vocab_coverage:.2f}")
print(f"Average Token Length: {average_token_length:.2f}")

